# TurfJS How to get LineString from Polygon reducing the applied buffer value

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson, turfjs

I created a buffered polygon for a LineString segment using the following:

`const bufferedPolygon = turf.buffer(featureGeoJson, bufferVal, 'kilometers');`

Is there any way I can process back the original LineString *featureGeoJson* from the now available bufferedPolygon and bufferVal?

I tried using [polygonToLine](https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygonToLine) method from turf, but I am still getting a polygon which is same as the buffered-polygon above with the **type** updated to *lineString*

Answer (score 1):

Well, `turf.buffer` creates a new object from the provided one and doesn't track its previous state. Also, as you said, `polygonToLine` as well as `polygonToLineString` are only going to convert the polygon boundary to a line string -- they don't function as the inverse of `buffer`.

What `turf.buffer` does do is keep the `properties` of the original feature. So we can do is save the original geometry into the line string's properties:

```
const linestring1 = turf.lineString([
    [-24, 63],
    [-23, 60],
    [-25, 65],
    [-20, 69]
], {
    name: 'line 1'
});

linestring1.properties.original_geometry = linestring1.geometry;

const bufferedPolygon = turf.buffer(linestring1, 2, {
    units: 'kilometers'
});
```

thereby preserving the original that you can revert to:

```
{
  "type":"Feature",
  "properties":{
    "name":"line 1",
    "original_geometry":{
      "type":"LineString",
      "coordinates":[[-24,63],[-23,60],[-25,65],[-20,69]]
    }
  },
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[...]
  }
}
```